# Error to mapping volume on Docker creating on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying create a Python server on Docker using image `python:3.6` and I'm using Windows. To do it I want map a Docker folder to a Windows folder but when I run the container can't find my `.py` file hosted on Windows.

The `run.py` file is at `C:/Users/augusto/Desktop/curso-docker/build-dev`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
LABEL maintainer 'Augusto'

RUN useradd www && \
    mkdir /app  && \
    mkdir /log  && \
    chown www /log

USER www
VOLUME /log
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python" ]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

**Run**

```
$ docker container run -it -v /host_mnt/c/users/augusto/desktop/curso-docker/build-dev:/app -p 80:8000 --name python-server build-dev
```

**Error msg**

```
/usr/local/bin/python: can't open file 'run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Why not `COPY` your application in the Dockerfile, and skip the `docker run -v` option?  (And use an ordinary non-Docker virtual environment for actual development?)

Comment: Yes, that's better. But in this case I want know the reasen that's not works.